# Oracle data import utility PIPELINE_UTL_PKG.DATA_UNLOAD

Tags: oracle

I am trying to understand one utility being used in an sql query to import data from database to a file. Below is the code being used for the same. Can anyone tell me if the below utility(`PIPELINE_UTL_PKG.DATA_UNLOAD`) is an oracle utility. I could not find anything in google for the same.

```
sql_exp='''SELECT * FROM TABLE(
      PIPELINE_UTL_PKG.DATA_UNLOAD(
        CURSOR(
          SELECT /*+ NO_PARALLEL(A) */ * FROM usr.tbl_extract A),
        'usr_tbl_extract.txt',
        'expdirectory',
        'N',
        'Y')
    )'''
    cur.execute(sql_exp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't an [Oracle supplied package](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/toc.htm); someone in your organisation or a supplier has created that.

If you aren't sure who owns it you can get the schema/owner from `all_objects`; you may see the package and a synonym. You can see what the package is doing by looking at the source code, which is in the `user_source` (if you're logged in as the owner) or `all_source` views.  It may be wrapped code - which isn't insurmountable - but if so you may have the source code stored externally, in a source control system.

Comment: Thank you .It is a package and data_unload is a function. It never crossed my mind to search in objects.